# covering spaces for globalize injectivity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, algebraic-topology

I'm studying differentiability and I have an observation: if $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a local diffeomorphism $C^{k}$, under what conditions will be global, ie under what conditions $f$ is injective?

I recommended study covering spaces, any suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f\; \text {guaranteed injective} \iff n=1$$

Hint for  contraposition of $\Rightarrow  : \quad  (x,y,z,\cdots)\mapsto (e^x \cos y,e^x \sin y,z,\cdots)$
Hint for $\Leftarrow $: $\quad f'$ does not change sign.